# Database access denied for AWS RDS proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

I have setup a RDS proxy for Aurora DB. I am able to connect to the RDS proxy endpoint but not able to perform any operations.

For e.g if I do show processlist; I get below error:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Database Access denied for user 'admin'@'ip-address' (using password: YES)

Note: I am able to access RDS endpoint and perform all the operations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked secret manager secret and compared to the username and password for the user?

Comment: @Riz yes, I am able to login with same credentials with rds endpoint

Comment: I added the wrong arn of secret manager in the IAM policy. check that also.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same issue. Turns out it was related to the auto-generated IAM role permissions.

The secrets manager had 2 user accounts added to it (with verified correct credentials), and both were added to the RDS proxy. However, only the first user account worked. The second user account would get a permission denied error.

Checking the CloudWatch logs, I saw a message similar to:

```
Credentials couldn't be retrieved. The IAM role "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/service-role/rds-proxy-role-TIMESTAMP" is not authorized to read the AWS Secrets Manager secret with the ARN "arn:aws:secretsmanager:REGION:ACCOUNT:secret:SECRET_NAME"
```

When I looked at the IAM policy for the `rds-proxy-role-TIMESTAMP` role, it had only been granted access to the secret for the first user. This appears to be an issue with the creation of the IAM role when the proxy is set up.

To resolve it, I modified the policy for the `rds-proxy-role-TIMESTAMP` role to give it access to the ARN for the second user's secret as well. After a few minutes, I was able to log in as the second user.

Comment: Same issue + resolution. It seems like the generated IAM scope was set to the original Secret ARN I used, but I switched secrets, and the IAM policy didn't have access to that secret.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a Database access denied error please check the user permissions in RDS first.

If you can connect to RDS directly with this credentials, check that credentials in Secret Manager are the same.

Then check if you RDS Proxy policy has permission to access all you Secret Manager records as I mention here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73649818/4642536